# Utilities.formatDate() returning month as 0

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

row[0] is a date formatted such that is shows as 8/16/22 in google sheets.

And for the code,

```
var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[0]), SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "m/d/yy");
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(date);
```

I expected the output of 8/16/22 but instead get the following:

[image: actual ouput]

My end goal is to have this date be pasted into a google doc template using the following line:

```
body.replaceText('{{date}}', date);
```

And here is the output of just `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(new Date(row[0]));`

[image: output without formatting]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written in [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

`m` is minute, use `M` instead.

Comment: Oh... looks like I was looking at the format patterns for google sheet and not apps script, thank you, will pay closer attention to that.